# Mismatch Exception Error when I try to use nextint() for File IO

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read both ints and strings from one text file using nextInt() and nextLine().

My text file looks like this:

```
1 vous avoir
vous allez
vous achetez
vous avons
vous êtes
2 je/j' étudier
je étudier
je écouteur
j'étudie
j'etudier
3 ils/elles faire
ils/elles sont
ils/elles ont
ils/elles font
ils/elles fait
4 tu venir
tu vient
tu viens
tu vois
tu as
5 il/elle aller
il/elle va
il/elle allons
il/elle a
il/elle est
```

My code looks like this:

```
while (inFile.hasNext())
{
    int temp = inFile.nextInt();
    if (temp == questionNum)
      {
        verb = inFile.next();
        form = inFile.next();
      }
    inFile.nextLine();
}
```

The error only happens when I write inFile.nextInt(). Could someone please explain to me how to fix this issue?

Comment: According to the docs an InputMismatchException will be throw  "if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range". It is problably happening when it tries to process the token "vous". You should use hasNextInt() fuunction to verify if the next token is really an int.

Comment: @marcellorvalle could you elaborate how I would integrate that into my while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well I managed to resolve my issue. I use a random int in order to choose which question I want from the text file, so I just converted that int into a string and made questionNum a string.

Here is the full code that I used:

```
while (inFile.hasNext() && counter < answerSet.length)
{
    String temp2 = inFile.nextLine();

    if (temp2.equals(questionNum))
       {
         //System.out.println(temp);
         verb = inFile.nextLine();
         form = inFile.nextLine();
         for (int i = 0; i < answerSet.length; i++) // this is to collect the answers after the verb and form in an array
         {
           answerSet[i] = inFile.nextLine();
         }
          System.out.println(verb + form);
       }
}
```

Thanks for all the help!